# Error while opening an excel workbook using C# code

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I'm trying to open an excel workbook and trying to get a worksheet in it. Excelapp.workbooks.Open line is throwing an Exception as

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open

Here is my code:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strWBPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
```

StrWbPath is my Excel location. I'm refering to 2007 excel and added Microsoft.office.interop.excel of version 12.0.0.0.

Comment: what type of application it is? console app? asp.net/winforms?

Answer (score 7):

(Sorry for answering this old question, but it's google result #1 for this problem and the correct answer is missing).

The error occurs because excel thinks the Workbook has been corrupted. When opening the Excel file, the last parameter tells excel how to handle this situation. Pass `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlExtractData` to instruct it to retrieve the data (This will open a popup telling the user excel tried to extract the data if the file is corrupted).

However, I noticed this problem can also be caused if the workbook you are trying to open has a different locale than your excel (was saved on a machine using another language setting) OR your system not having the en-us locale set.

While this is extremely stupid, it's easy to overcome. For me the solution was to just set the current locale to en-us before opening the file:

```
static System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI;
oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlExtractData);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;
```

credit goes to [this page](http://www.made4dotnet.com/Default.aspx?tabid=141&aid=15)

Answer (score 0):

What if you try System.Reflection.Missing.Value instead of Type.Missing?

Regards,

M.

Answer (score 0):

Which class are you using?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
```

if this then try changing it to

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, I lost tons of time on this one.  I was passing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile` for the CorruptedLoad parameter for all files, thinking it meant "open the file, and if it's corrupt, attempt a repair".  This worked for most files.

However, for some files, I was still getting the exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC).  Yet if you open the file in Excel manually, it is not corrupt.

It turned out that for those files, you *must not* supply the CorruptedLoad parameter.  Then it opens successfully.  So in the end I adjusted my code to first try without any CorruptedLoad parameter, and only if that returns the exception, then try passing xlRepairFile for that parameter.  I also adjusted my understanding of that parameter to mean "open and repair this file regardless of whether it's corrupt".