# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while opening a file with interop, error message Excel cannot continue this task with the available ressources

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm getting an error message saying that Excel can't continue this task with the available ressources and then an Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC, and I think it has something to do with my Excel Application which I try to use only once and use for all the operations in My App,
This is My Declaration of the instance:

```
namespace VID
{
    public partial class VID_MAIN_FORM : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
        public static Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        System.Threading.ManualResetEvent _busy = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
        Dictionary<string,Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>, List<Tuple<string, string>>,string>> FinalReportErrorList = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>,List<Tuple<string,string>>,string>>();
        Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>,List<Tuple<string,string>>,string> Creator_Error;
        Dictionary<string,Tuple<string, string, string,Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string>>,string>> SFinalReportErrorList = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>,string>>();
        Tuple<string, string, string, Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string>>,string> ServiceErrors;
        //TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs;
```

and the error occurs over here when I call `xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFile);`:

```
    private Tuple<string,string,string> VerifyProvider(Tuple<string,string> Provider, string xlFile, string xlSpreadsheet)
    {
        Tuple<string, string, string> ProviderInfos;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        string xlFileName = xlFile.Remove(0, xlFile.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        bool exist = false;
        if (SrcIsOpen(xlFileName))
        {
            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks[xlFileName];
        }
        else
        {
            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFile);
        }
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[xlSpreadsheet];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

Thanks for Your Help In Advance !

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699936/error-while-opening-an-excel-workbook-using-c-sharp-code)
 and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706258/workbooks-open-method-throwing-hresult-0x800a03ec)?

Comment: Sorry for leaving this unanswered, thanks @AlexButenko, I've found out a solution to the problem using the links you provided, thank you for the help :)